# React map over collection from firebase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling with Google Firebase Realtime database but I can't create an array of the collection.

When I loop the const return in console log I get all the messages as separate objects but I just want the messages to come in a large array so I can loop here. I hope someone can help me on my way.

Here is my code so far:

```
// Libraries
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from 'firebase/database';

// Components
import Container from '~/common/Container';

import '~/utils/firebase';

export interface MessageProps {
  messageId?: string;
  content?: string;
  likes?: number;
  timestamp?: number;
  user?: string;
}

/**
 * Homepage
 *
 * @returns {JSX.Element}
 */
const Home: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessageProps[]>([{}]);
  const db = getDatabase();
  const dbMessage = ref(db, 'messages/');

  useEffect(() => {
    onValue(dbMessage, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        const messageData = childSnapshot.val();
        setMessages([
          ...messages,
          {
            content: messageData.content,
            likes: messageData.likes,
            timestamp: messageData.likes,
            user: messageData.user,
          },
        ]);
      });
    }, {
      onlyOnce: true,
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(messages);

  return (
    <Container>
      <p>Map (loop) comes here...</p>
    </Container>
  );
};

// Connect and export
export default Home;
```

I have tried to fix this with useEffect, but I think this is not needed but let me know. I'm thinking I'm getting close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `useEffect` you're calling `setMessages` for each child node in the results. Things will be much faster, if you only call `setMessages` once after processing all child nodes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  onValue(dbMessage, (snapshot) => {
    let data = [];
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      const messageData = childSnapshot.val();
      data.push(messageData);
    });
    console.log(data);
    setMessages(data);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Sound logical but I got an typescript warning on part: "data.push(messageData)" and than on messageData with the text: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. But I put // @ts-ignore above it and than this is exactly what i want! Thanks!